# Need help using Selenium Chromedriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to print each merchant name next to "his" price of the page like this:

Climaconvenienza    1.031,79 €

Hwonline                 1.031,80 €

Shopdigit                1.073,90 €

The code I made is this:

```py
browser.get('https://www.trovaprezzi.it/televisori-lcd-plasma/prezzi-scheda-prodotto/lg_oled_cx3?sort=prezzo_totale')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".merchant_name_and_logo img")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".merchant_name_and_logo img"))) 

names = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".merchant_name_and_logo img")

for span in names:
    print(span.get_attribute("alt"))
    
all_divs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_total_price']")
for div in all_divs:
    print(div.text)
```

But, by running my code, I get this:

Climaconvenienza

Hwonline

Shopdigit

1.031,79 €

1.031,80 €

1.073,90 €

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `names` and `all_divs` always have the same length (as they do in your example), the following should work:

```
browser.get('https://www.trovaprezzi.it/televisori-lcd-plasma/prezzi-scheda-prodotto/lg_oled_cx3?sort=prezzo_totale')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".merchant_name_and_logo img")))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".merchant_name_and_logo img"))) 

names = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".merchant_name_and_logo img")
all_divs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='item_total_price']")

for i in range(len(names)):
    print(names[i].get_attribute("alt") + ' ' + all_divs[i].text)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will print a list of sellers and the prices. You can modify the output in accordance with your needs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

browser.get('https://www.trovaprezzi.it/televisori-lcd-plasma/prezzi-scheda-prodotto/lg_oled_cx3?sort=prezzo_totale')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".merchant_name_and_logo img")))

listings = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".listing_item.clearfix")

result = []
for listing in listings:
    name = listing.find_element_by_css_selector(".merchant_name_and_logo img").get_attribute("alt")
    price = listing.find_element_by_css_selector(".item_total_price").text
    result.append([name, price])

print(*result, sep='\n')
```

My output:

```
['Climaconvenienza', 'Tot. 1.031,79 €']
['Hwonline', 'Tot. 1.031,80 €']
['Shopdigit', 'Tot. 1.073,90 €']
['eBay', 'Tot. 1.085,00 €']
['ePrice', 'Tot. 1.123,99 €']
['Onlinestore', 'Tot. 1.124,80 €']
['Hwonline', 'Tot. 1.129,90 €']
['Shoppyssimo', 'Tot. 1.148,00 €']
['Prezzo forte', 'Tot. 1.166,39 €']
['eBay', 'Tot. 1.181,26 €']
['eBay', 'Tot. 1.193,42 €']
['eBay', 'Tot. 1.199,00 €']
['eBay', 'Tot. 1.244,91 €']
['eBay', 'Tot. 1.249,00 €']
['eBay', 'Tot. 1.269,62 €']
['Yeppon', 'Tot. 1.288,89 €']
['Showprice', 'Tot. 1.301,80 €']
['Galagross', 'Tot. 1.419,99 €']
['Climaconvenienza', 'Tot. 1.519,17 €']
['Di Lella Shop', 'Tot. 1.519,17 €']
```

To print without brackets use:

```
for item in result:
  print(item[0], ', '.join(map(str, item[1:])))
```

Comment: Nice answer, your for loop makes more sense than mine :)

Comment: @C.Peck  Thanks, It prints list of lists initially, I've added a solution on how to remove these inner brackets. There should be prettier ones.

Comment: Nice solution, just one step ahead from what we do yesterday :)